# Select2 the indentation of the search input is hidden behind the tag

Tags: input, jquery-select2

.select2-container .select2-search__field This search field is having an inline style for the input.
In my scenario I am using select2 for multiple selections and after selecting a tag, I start to type to search for the second tag and the 2 characters are hidden behind the select2 tag.

I was able to fix that with hardcoding the styling of css like his:
`.select2-container .select2-search__field { width: 100% !important; }`
Isn't there another solution to fix this select2 bug ?